# Code Review Cumulative Totals of List Taking Snapshots at Index Python

Tags: python, list, indexing, list-comprehension, cumulative-sum

another question about cumulative totals. Consider the following code:

```
json_message = {'result':[[12,  234],  [53,  45],  [3,  425],  [74,  12],  [3,  678],  [2,  42],  [12,  234],  [1,  66],  [6,  85],  [5,  73],  [12,  84],  [6,  24],  [98,  23],  [34,  4],  [82,  253]]}
total = 0
totals = [{'length': 1, 'total': 0},  {'length': 4, 'total': 0}, {'length': 7, 'total': 0}, {'length': 10, 'total': 0}, {'length': 15, 'total': 0}]

for index,  item in enumerate(json_message['result'][::-1]):
    total += round(float(item[1]),  2)
    if index == totals[0]['length']-1:
        totals[0]['total'] = total
    elif index == totals[1]['length']-1:
        totals[1]['total'] = total
    elif index == totals[2]['length']-1:
        totals[2]['total'] = total
    elif index == totals[3]['length']-1:
        totals[3]['total'] = total
    elif index == totals[4]['length']-1:
        totals[4]['total'] = total

print(totals)
```

I have a list of lists within json_message['result'], I'd like to get the sum of the 2nd int in each list getting a cumulative total at every nth index (indicated by length), in reverse. The code works, just looking for a more elegant solution.

I've also tried

```
json_message = {'result':[[12,  234],  [53,  45],  [3,  425],  [74,  12],  [3,  678],  [2,  42],  [12,  234],  [1,  66],  [6,  85],  [5,  73],  [12,  84],  [6,  24],  [98,  23],  [34,  4],  [82,  253]]}
total = 0
totals = [{'length': 1, 'total': 0},  {'length': 4, 'total': 0}, {'length': 7, 'total': 0}, {'length': 10, 'total': 0}, {'length': 15, 'total': 0}]

ind = (1, 4, 7, 10)

for index,  item in enumerate([[x[1] for x in json_message['result'][::-1]][start:stop] for start,stop in zip((0,)+ind, ind+(len(json_message['result']),))]):
for x in item:
    total += round(float(x),  2)
totals[index]['total'] = total

print(totals)
```

This also works, definitely shorter, not as elegant as I'd like. It works by seperating the second int int the list and reversing them by list comprehension. Then slices them into 5 list and finds the cumulative sum of each list.

Suggestions from the experts would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to import numpy for such a simple task, something like this should work just fine:

```
cumulative = 0
for index, itm in enumerate(json_message['result'][::-1]):
    cumulative += itm[1]
    if index+1 in ind:
        print(cumulative)
print(cumulative)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was after, brain just wasn't working right.

Comment: On second thought (brain still not working correctly), this doesn't work as there isn't a way to associate/store the totals with ind. Any other ideas?

Comment: You just need to add something like `totals = {}` and `totals[index+1] = cumulative` inside of the ìf` condition. Just use the dictionary structure that you need for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` module:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array(json_message['result'][::-1], dtype='float64').round(2).T[1]
# json_message['result'][::-1] reverses the 2d list
# Don't really know why there is round(float(x), 2) in your code, that's why 
# .round(2) will to round to 2 decimal places
# .T gives us the transpose of the 2d array, in your case
# to make it easier to get 2nd element, i.e., 2nd column here

for d in totals:
    d['total'] = sum(x[:d['length']])
    # x[:d['length']] will give the array upto the length mentioned (length mentioned is actually 'length+1', so no calculation in slicing)
print(totals)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pprint import pprint
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import accumulate

json_message = {'result': [[12, 234], [53, 45], [3, 425], [74, 12], [3, 678], [2, 42], [12, 234], [1, 66], [6, 85], [5, 73], [12, 84], [6, 24], [98, 23], [34, 4], [82, 253]]}
totals = [{'length': 1, 'total': 0}, {'length': 4, 'total': 0}, {'length': 7, 'total': 0}, {'length': 10, 'total': 0}, {'length': 15, 'total': 0}]

def update_totals(totals, json_message):
    # build a lookup map of the positions we want
    lookup_map = {result['length'] - 1: result for result in totals}

    # extract the results
    sequence_of_results = reversed(json_message['result'])

    # from each result, extract the particular data item
    sequence_of_values = map(itemgetter(1), sequence_of_results)

    # take the running total
    running_total = accumulate(sequence_of_values)

    # update the output structure with the running total
    for index, value in enumerate(running_total):
        if index in lookup_map:
            lookup_map[index]['total'] = value

update_totals(totals, json_message)
pprint(totals)
```

All I did was break down the steps, with an iterator based solution. Since each iterator feeds into the next, I could have done a bunch of that on one line, but that wouldn't have been very readable. Also note that the standard library already provides the tools you need, like itertools.accumultate.

You may want to separate the underlying data structure from how you display it. This "totals" data structure seems like you're baking in a lot of code from the display function (not provided) into this simple for loop.

I probably would have used tuples for the data points in the json_message['result], and named tuples would be so much more readable, but that's probably outside of your control.

I kind of ignored the problem with floating point numbers, but there are issues with forcing your integers to float. Search stack overflow for "is floating point math broken." If the actual data is float, there may be a concern.

Comment: Wait, this is the wrong SO board for a code review. This probably should have been on stackexchange. Oh well.